# How do I silence output to stdout in rpy2?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I have an R function that I call from my Python script using rpy2. The R function prints to stdout; is there a parameter in rpy2 that silences stdout when an R script is called?

Comment: You can stop `stdout` writing by using `StringIO`.  In Python 2 that's in the `StringIo` module, and in Python 3 in the `io` module.

Comment: From the R side, you can use `invisible(expression)` to hide the print method

Answer (score 2):

rpy2 lets you redefine R's own interaction with a terminal as python function.

The following example from the documentation shows how to append output
to `stdout` to a Python list (limited usefulness in the grand scheme of things, but it makes a simple examples of the feature):

```
buf = []
def f(x):
    # function that append its argument to the list 'buf'
    buf.append(x)

consolewrite_print_backup = (rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks
                             .consolewrite_print)
# output from the R console will now be appended to the list 'buf'
rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks.consolewrite_print = f

date = rinterface.baseenv['date']
rprint = rinterface.baseenv['print']
rprint(date())

# the output is in our list (as defined in the function f above)
print(buf)


# restore default function
rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks.consolewrite_print = consolewrite_print_backup
```

The documentation is here: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/callbacks.html#write-console

Comment: This does not seem to work with the latest version of `rpy2` which is 3.3.5 as of writing.

Comment: @xApple - The answer is for an older version of rpy2. The documentation for rpy2-3.3.5 has a the version that works for the matching version. The answer was edited to point to the latest version of the doc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @lgautier doesn't work in the latest of `rpy2` which is 3.3.5 as of writing.

This method can be attached to a class, and will capture all of R's output into two attributes, after being called once.

```
def capture_r_output(self):
    """
    Will cause all the output that normally goes to the R console,
    to end up instead in a python list.
    """
    # Import module #
    import rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks
    # Record output #
    self.stdout = []
    self.stderr = []
    # Dummy functions #
    def add_to_stdout(line): self.stdout.append(line)
    def add_to_stderr(line): self.stderr.append(line)
    # Keep the old functions #
    self.stdout_orig = rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks.consolewrite_print
    self.stderr_orig = rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks.consolewrite_warnerror
    # Set the call backs #
    rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks.consolewrite_print     = add_to_stdout
    rpy2.rinterface_lib.callbacks.consolewrite_warnerror = add_to_stderr
```